# Minimal normal subgroup contained in a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup is abelian

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

I am studying the classification of sharply k-transitive groups, and I am reading a proof that sharply $2$-transitive groups are contained in an affine group: Aff($GF(p)$).

One of the steps it makes to show this is confusing, and I feel hesitant to believe it. It is that if we have a minimal normal subgroup $N \subseteq G$ where $N$ is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup, $P$, that is also normal in $G$, then $N$ is not only normal in $G$, but also abelian.

The book states that this is because since $N$ is $p$-group, the center of $N$ is nontrivial. I know this to be true, and I'm guessing that since the center of $N$ is nontrivial, some argument using these facts can be made to show that $Z(N) = N$, but I am stumped here.

Comment: The center is a so called characteristic subgroup, so if $N$ is normal in $G$, then the center of $N$ is also normal in $G$. By minimality, we get that the center is either trivial or the whole of $N$.

Comment: I see this now, and have found a proof of this fact earlier in the book. Thank you!